# Let A be an $m \times n$ matrix, using matrix algebra prove that

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

$\left<Ax, y\right> = \left<x, A^Ty\right>$

for all x in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and all y in $\mathbb{R}^m$

So this one was pretty simple for me, or at least that's what i think...

anyway.. my work is down below...

1) i removed the $\left<\right>$ because i know it is just the dot product

$Ax\cdot y = x\cdot A^Ty$

2) I then applied the rule $(AB)^T$ = $(B^TA^T)$ to the left hand side of the equation

$x\cdot A^Ty = x\cdot A^Ty$

is this the correct way of proving the original equation? did i make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct, simply note that for the properties of inner product:

$$\left<Ax, y\right> =(Ax)^Ty=x^TA^Ty=x^T(A^Ty)=\left<x, A^Ty\right>$$